# Correct timeout value for keep-alive HTTP connections

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, timeout, keep-alive

Im looking an enabling `keep-alive` via the `.htacess` file. Ive read about enabling the `timeout` param which would allow me to specify a cut of time for the `keep-alive` in specifying this what would a good value be ?

The average site load of the home page takes 2.9s (the homepage is almost 14mb of which 98% of that is full screen images, but we lazy load the images so the impact on page load in negligible, the first 2 images and html, css, js are all thats loaded in the first instance hence the 2.9s page load)

The rest of the images take up to 30s to download in the background (this is timed with a non `keep-alive` connection).

Baring that in mind what would an optimal `timeout` be ? Would setting 30s be ok (is there a downside to going over ?) If we went under does that just mean the client would establish another connection and the site would be loaded in multiple `keep-alive` chunks ?

For reference to how much load the server can take the site has c. 150-200 visits per day (peak visits per hour are 20-30). The server is a 512gb of ram, VPS with 1tb monthly transfer quota.

Comment: You cannot control that through a `.htaccess` file. The [`KeepAlive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#keepalive) directive needs to be set host- or serverwide.

Comment: Err ... 1TB bandwidth!? I assume that is your per-month traffic quota?

Comment: @DaSourcerer I was under the impression this could be set via the `.htaccess file` if you search for "keep-alive .htaccess" on google, multiple sites detail how to do it like this one - https://varvy.com/pagespeed/keep-alive.html - re. 1TB bandwidth correct thats the monthly traffic quota, ive updated the question to correct that

Comment: Ah, that's a different way. The `KeepAlive` directive is Apache's native way of handling that and won't work through `.htaccess`. The linked solution achieves the same by simply setting a header through `mod_headers`. I advise using the native solution.

Comment: Ah ok, either way what would the best approach be in terms of setting the timeout param ?

Comment: It depends. `KeepAlive` is on by default anyway. I'd rather be concerned with [`MaxKeepAlive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#maxkeepaliverequests) and [`KeepAliveTimeout`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#KeepAliveTimeout). If you increase the timeout to 30s, you are at five times the default value. That can turn problematic if you see many concurrent connections.

Comment: @DaSourcerer when you say `keepalive` is on by default ive actualy found that bare bones CentOS LAMP installs on Digital Ocean dont have it enabled, in that case i guess its worth turning it on manually

Comment: That must have been done on DO's behalf, though. Apache and CentOS have it enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

I would set it to 60 sec, just to be sure that an unforeseen peak load does not causes any problems.

Comment: Thanks @Dexion any particular reason behind the 60s ? Is there a default setting if none is specified by keepalive is enabled ? . Good point about any peak load, looking at the VPS usage stats the website seems to run max at about 5-10% load with 200 visits a day, do i think were probally fine on that front, but worth baring in mind if we were closer to the limit.

Comment: just a value what i have used ;)